# Confusing result in TSQL when incrementing varbinary

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @V AS VARBINARY(8)
SET @V = 0x000000003B654036;
SELECT @V as 'Before'
Set @V = @V+0x0000000000000001;
SELECT @V as 'After'

Before: 0x000000003B654036
After: 0x000000003B654036


Expanding the varbinary result to a larger value I see where the 0x0000000000000001 is going

DECLARE @V AS VARBINARY(8);
DECLARE @R AS VARBINARY(max);
SET @V = 0x000000003B654036;
SELECT @V as 'Before';
SET @R = @V +0x0000000000000001;
SELECT @R as 'After' ;

Before: 0x000000003B654036
After: 0x000000003B6540360000000000000001
```

But I'm Looking for a result that comes to 0x000000003B65407, how do i get that just by adding 1 to the binary value.

Comment: odd results at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4f39/1 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VARBINARY` in T-SQL is more like a binary string datatype, so the `+` operator concatenates the two values instead of executing a mathematical addition. That makes sense as SQL Server does not know if you are storing an integer, a float, or a jpeg image in that field.

In your case, as you have 8 bytes, you could to this:

```
DECLARE @V AS VARBINARY(8)
DECLARE @W AS VARBINARY(8)
SET @V = 0x000000003B654036;
SELECT @V as 'Before'
Set @W = 0x0000000000000001;
SET @V = CAST( CAST(@V AS BIGINT) + CAST(@W AS BIGINT) AS VARBINARY(8));
SELECT @V as 'After'
```

If you have more than 8 bytes, you have to write your own addition code. In that case I would consider CLR.

You also might want to look at using `BINARY(8)` instead of `VARBINARY(8)` if all your values are alway 8 bytes long. That would safe a little room on disk, as SQL Server does not have to store the length with every row anymore.

Comment: Will the casting and any possible truncation result in different values between SQL Servers... it's noted on the varbinary and binary types in msdn...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx
Conversions between any data type and the binary data types are not guaranteed to be the same between versions of SQL Server.

Comment: Well, there is a risk in that. However, with the BIGINT data type it is very unlikely that this will ever change, as long as you execute on a 64 bit or higher Intel processor platform. If you need to be 100% future proof (instead of just 99.9999%), you have to do your own one-byte-at-a-time calculation or better use a CLR data type and handle the calculation in C#. I personally would add a test for this to my automated unit test suite and go with the CAST. If it ever breaks, the test will tell me.

Comment: Just to be clear, you need 8 tests for that. What would change is the byte order which might cause erros on overflow operations. Something like 0x0000f000 + 0x00001000 resulting in 0x00000001 instead of 0x00010000

Comment: This method solved the issue... perfect! Thanks!  I just used the casting and if the values end up off we'll deal with it then.